# How to get Size of a object (class, structure) in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am attempting to perform a perverse memory trick by calculating the size of an object (one of many in a serial fashion), so I can jump forward in the memory stream to the next one.

This is for a managed class. I've seen reference to sizeof and Mashal.SizeOf, but they appeared in reference to unmanaged types or value types.

So, does anyone know a way to do this at runtime, or should I break out the calculator and it do it manually in the code?

Comment: What "memory stream" are you talking about? If you're talking about the *serialized* size of an object, that could be very different to the size in memory.

Comment: A file stream, essentially. I am writing some code to parse an xml file manually, which is contained in a zip file. Since I want to speed things up, and only need to parse out the occasional item, I'd like to be able to pre-calculate the object's size so I can skip ahead. For instance, if I have 20 of these objects, but I only need the first and twelfth one, I'd like to say some time, by calculating the jump, instead of parsing line by line until I get to my target.

Comment: That depends on how the managed object is serialized into the MemoryStream. Can you show us your serialization code?

Comment: @user978122: So you're actually interested in the size of an XML representation of an object? Why didn't you mention XML in the question?

Comment: On top, common sense (!) says that the size of the object depends on data. See, number. An int has a fixed number of bytes in memory, but there is a difference in text between "0" and "30000". As such, there is no static size for most XML elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant get size of object if you dont use unsafe coding (marshal)
You can use a tool like:

CLR Profiler
VSTS Profiler
.NET Memory Profiler

Comment: How is that an answer given that the poster talks of a XML data stream, not in memory stuff?

Comment: Allow me to explain: mekici's answer is that it's not worth attempting to get the size of a data structure in C#, as the CLR is making size estimates kind of funny. Given that, I've opted to use calculated data structure sizes, as least for the short run. I am attempting to do something which uses a data stream, which for all intensive purposes can be treated sort of like an array in memory.